# @react-google-maps/api production build is broken

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

React app production build stopped working. The generated chunk can not be loaded, because the output of the build generates the following line:

```
google.maps.LatLng(85.02070771743472,-178.41fa87a0d75)
```

instead of:

```
google.maps.LatLng(85.02070771743472, -178.48388434375)
```

Package versions:

- react: 18.0.0
- @react-google-maps/api: 2.12.0

Tried solutions, which did not help to fix the problem

- Changing the version of google maps to 3.47, 3.48, 3.49
- Downgrading the version of the @react-google-maps/api

Is there a solution to fix this problem? What could possibly cause this change of constant value during the production build?

[Row in codebase](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/blob/2b70630dff698032a58ae83ef85ef81165422ecb/packages/react-google-maps-api-marker-clusterer/src/Clusterer.tsx#L731)

Answer (score 0):

We managed to locate the issue, but not the root cause. We were importing a component

```
import { MenuItem } from 'sharedComponents/Page/UserSignedMenu'
```

from the file:

```
export const MenuItem = styled('a')`
  some styling
`
```

The solution was to not import the component, but copy it to that file where it is used. It is a dirty fix, and violating the DRY concept, but solving the production build.

We tried to not use the styled component, just a simple div:

```
export const MenuItem = <div>test</div>
```

But did not help.